# How can I stop Fail2ban from banning my external IP when attempting to access my Plex server?

Tags: nginx-reverse-proxy, fail2ban

I have a fairly simple setup using fail2ban with NGINX Proxy Manager. In this setup, I have Plex exposed to the outside and routed internally using my reverse proxy, and that works fine without fail2ban. The problem is when I try to use fail2ban, my external IP immediately gets banned when attempting to access my Plex server. If I check my proxy host access logs, I'm getting successive 401 errors that seem to match the regex filter in fail2ban's filter.d directory. Here is my regex filter:

```
[INCLUDES]

[Definition]

failregex = ^.* (405|404|403|401|\-) (405|404|403|401) - .* \[Client <HOST>\] \[Length .*\] .* \[Sent-to <F-CONTAINER>.*</F-CONTAINER>\] <F-USERAGENT>".*"</F-USERAGENT> .*$
ignoreregex = ^.* (404|\-) (404) - .*".*(\.png|\.txt|\.jpg|\.ico|\.js|\.css)(/)*?" \[Client <HOST>\] \[Length .*\] ".*" .*$
```

In my jail.d config, I have 'maxretry' set to 4, and the 'logpath' specifically includes all the nginx proxy manager's proxy host access and error logs. Here is that config:

```
[npm-docker]
enabled = true
ignoreip = 127.0.0.1/8 10.10.10.0/24 10.10.0.0/24
action = cloudflare-apiv4
         %(action_mwl)s
chain = INPUT
logpath = /log/npm/default-host_access.log
          /log/npm/proxy-host-*_access.log
          /log/npm/proxy-host-*_error.log
maxretry = 4
bantime  = -1
findtime = 86400
destemail = <My email address>
sender = fail2ban@notification
sendername = fail2ban
```

And as referenced in the first paragraph, If I look at the the plex proxy host access log, I can find four 401 errors when I attempted to access my plex server at the time it was banned from a mobile client with an outside IP:

```
[09/Jun/2023:19:24:58 -0700] - 200 200 - GET https <redacted url> "/?X-Plex-Language=en-US&X-Plex-Device-Name=iPhone" [Client <redacted ipv6>] [Length 4266] [Gzip -] [Sent-to 10.10.10.4] "PlexMobile/8.20 (iPhone; iOS 16.5; Scale/3.00)" "-"
[09/Jun/2023:19:24:58 -0700] - 401 401 - GET https <redacted url> "/media/subscriptions/scheduled?X-Plex-Language=en-US&X-Plex-Device-Name=iPhone" [Client <redacted ipv6>] [Length 82] [Gzip -] [Sent-to 10.10.10.4] "PlexMobile/8.20 (iPhone; iOS 16.5; Scale/3.00)" "-"
[09/Jun/2023:19:24:58 -0700] - 200 200 - GET https <redacted url> "/media/providers" [Client <redacted ipv6>] [Length 4849] [Gzip -] [Sent-to 10.10.10.4] "PlexMediaServer/1.29.0.6244-819d3678c" "-"
[09/Jun/2023:19:24:58 -0700] - 200 200 - GET https <redacted url> "/media/providers?includePreferences=1&X-Plex-Language=en-US&X-Plex-Device-Name=iPhone" [Client <redacted ipv6>] [Length 8849] [Gzip -] [Sent-to 10.10.10.4] "PlexMobile/8.20 (iPhone; iOS 16.5; Scale/3.00)" "-"
[09/Jun/2023:19:24:58 -0700] - 401 401 - GET https <redacted url> "/activities?X-Plex-Language=en-US&X-Plex-Device-Name=iPhone" [Client <redacted ipv6>] [Length 82] [Gzip -] [Sent-to 10.10.10.4] "PlexMobile/8.20 (iPhone; iOS 16.5; Scale/3.00)" "-"
[09/Jun/2023:19:24:58 -0700] - 401 401 - GET https <redacted url> "/media/subscriptions?includeGrabs=1&X-Plex-Language=en-US&X-Plex-Device-Name=iPhone" [Client <redacted ipv6>] [Length 82] [Gzip -] [Sent-to 10.10.10.4] "PlexMobile/8.20 (iPhone; iOS 16.5; Scale/3.00)" "-"
[09/Jun/2023:19:24:58 -0700] - 200 200 - GET https <redacted url> "/clients?X-Plex-Language=en-US&X-Plex-Device-Name=iPhone" [Client <redacted ipv6>] [Length 90] [Gzip -] [Sent-to 10.10.10.4] "PlexMobile/8.20 (iPhone; iOS 16.5; Scale/3.00)" "-"
[09/Jun/2023:19:24:58 -0700] - 401 401 - GET https <redacted url> "/activities?X-Plex-Language=en-US&X-Plex-Device-Name=iPhone" [Client <redacted ipv6>] [Length 82] [Gzip -] [Sent-to 10.10.10.4] "PlexMobile/8.20 (iPhone; iOS 16.5; Scale/3.00)" "-"
[09/Jun/2023:19:24:58 -0700] - 200 200 - GET https <redacted url> "/media/providers?includePreferences=1&X-Plex-Language=en-US&X-Plex-Device-Name=iPhone" [Client <redacted ipv6>] [Length 8849] [Gzip -] [Sent-to 10.10.10.4] "PlexMobile/8.20 (iPhone; iOS 16.5; Scale/3.00)" "-"
```

I've only modified the above log to remove the public IP and URL. My question is, since the 401's here aren't really affecting my access as I'm still being authenticated, is there a way to change my regex filter to get Fail2ban to ignore these particular entries (I admit that I don't know much about regex), or is it better to change some specific part of my configuration in the NGINX proxy manager, and if so, what would that be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into the same problem - same setup - fail2ban, nginx proxy manager and cloudflare dns (not tunnels). #1 - you should add your public IP to the ignoreip section of your jail file. As for the filter, this is not the most elegant solution as I'm not a regex ninja, but this is what I landed on.

```
 failregex = ^<HOST>.+" (4\d\d|3\d\d) (\d\d\d|\d) .+$
        
             ^.+ 4\d\d \d\d\d - .+ \[Client <HOST>\] \[Length .+\] ".+" .+$

 ignoreregex = ^\s*(?:\[\]\s+)?- 4\d\d \d+ - [A-Z]+ \w+ \S+ "\/video\/:\/transcode\/.+?(?=")" \[Client <ADDR>]
          
               ^\s*(?:\[\]\s+)?- 4\d\d \d+ - [A-Z]+ \w+ \S+ "\/photo\/:\/transcode\/.+?(?=")" \[Client <ADDR>]
```

The ignoreregex looks for a new log line with a 400 error, specifically then the /video:/transcode and /photo:/transcode callouts, and then finally the Client IP Address. I was getting random 400 errors when movie posters or actor photos were missing causing bans. I'm still unclear what the /media/subscriptions and /media/providers errors are referring to. Honestly I see them fail from IPs I don't recognize and get banned so I'm not sure yet if I want to ignore them. If you have any detail there I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Thank you for this. I'm going to assume this works, but I have since moved to Traefik using a json access log. I was able to find a regex that worked pretty well for that, so far anyway. I would share it here but the message is too long. With that being said, I can't test your regex, but I'll still mark your post as the answer.